# Image Rendering on HTML with base64?

Tags: javascript, html, image, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on uploading images, and loading them back to the browser with Node.js and mongoose. When the user registers, I was able let them upload the image. Then I store the image into mongodb. Below, picture is sent from the client, and image is what I send to the server.

```
var match = /data:([^;]+);base64,(.*)/.exec(picture);

var image = {
    data: new Buffer(match[2], "base64"),
    contentType: match[1]
};
```

Before converting it with buffer the format is:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJwAAACgCAIAAAB2YpLMAAAYT2..==
```

After conversion image.data is in this format:

```
<Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00>
```

However, when I try to retrieve the image back to the client, the html would be:

```
data:image/png;base64,105,86,66,79,82,119,48,75,71,103,...
```

It could not load the image on the browser, and i think i need to have it in this format:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJwAAACgCAIAAAB2YpLMAAAYT2...==
```

How would i fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `toString("base64")` on image.data to get it back in original string form.